# vaadin-item @click event in lit template

Tags: web-component, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14, lit

I'm trying to build a page size selector for the vaadin-grid-pagination project and in doing so I came up with a design that uses the vaadin-dropdown-menu webcomponents and looks like this:

```
<vaadin-dropdown-menu label="Page Size">
  <template>
    <vaadin-list-box>
      <vaadin-item @click="${event => this.setLimit(10)}">10</vaadin-item>
      <vaadin-item @click="${event => this.setLimit(25)}">25</vaadin-item>
      <vaadin-item @click="${event => this.setLimit(50)}">50</vaadin-item>
      <vaadin-item @click="${event => this.setLimit(100)}">100</vaadin-item>
   </vaadin-list-box>
 </template>
</vaadin-dropdown-menu>
```

The problem I`m having is that the @click event doesn't seem to be fired. In a previous attempt I've used the shibui-dropdown webcomponent for achieving the same thing and that one worked fine, I was able to pass the value selected in the UI using the @click event.

Why I chose to go with the  is that it has the look and feel of the general vaadin theme and would look better overall.

What am I doing wrong in not being able to trigger the @click event ?

Comment: as far as I can see vaadin-item doesn't have a click event https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-web-components/22.0.0-beta1/#/elements/vaadin-item

Comment: I think the <vaadin-list-box> should have an event handler like @selected-changed as per the API ?!